# Set goal in funnel not to be necessary

Tags: google-analytics, goals, goal-tracking

I have a start page which can link to a discounts page and then three possible extras pages (one of which will definitely be reached), all three of these lead to a confirmation page.

*I have set up goals on each page and on the confirmation page I have the following funnel:*

1. `/G1/StartPage`
2. `/G1/(Extra1|Extra2|Extra3)Page`

*However I want to include the discounts page, but not all customers can see that page. e.g.*

1. `/G1/StartPage`
2. `/G1/DiscountsPage` (may not be read)
3. `/G1/(Extra1|Extra2|Extra3)Page`

*Question(s):*

- Can I do this in the same funnel? do I have to keep my current funnel above?
- If I create a separate funnel (of which the goal is the confirmation page again) would I only include the discounts page?

Comment: Sorry, meant to send it over to webmasters.

Comment: It's important to note that funnels don't actually affect Goals. ie, the only things that funnels affect are funnel visualizations. You can create a required step, but it will only affect what traffic is filtered through the funnel, not whether the goal itself is actually executed.

Answer (score 2):

I think GA will only give you the option to make Step 1 optional, so you may have to make a separate funnel.